# Inset box shadow faded/transparent on the left and right edges

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an inset box shadow that has transparency/fades out on the left and right edges of a div. I managed to add a normal inset box shadow but I don't know how to add transparency to the edges. How can I do this?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

```css
  .container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: rgb(178, 169, 169) 0px 8px 8px -8px inset, rgb(178, 169, 169) 0px -8px 8px -8px inset;
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it using `radial-gradient`. Check this fiddle

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}
.banner{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}

.banner::before{
    content: "";
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="banner"></div>
</div>
```